# Help with Collapsible Divs (adding image for show/hide state)

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this script for collapsible divs...

http://www.harrymaugans.com/2007/03/06/how-to-create-an-animated-sliding-collapsible-div-with-javascript-and-css/

Everything's working fine but I need to add an image for show/hide state. When the div is showing the header displays an "open" arrow...when closed it displays a "closed" arrow. Any help is really appreciated!! Thanks :)

Here's the JS...

```
var timerlen = 5;
var slideAniLen = 250;

var timerID = new Array();
var startTime = new Array();
var obj = new Array();
var endHeight = new Array();
var moving = new Array();
var dir = new Array();

function slidedown(objname){
        if(moving[objname])
                return;

        if(document.getElementById(objname).style.display != "none")
                return; // cannot slide down something that is already visible

        moving[objname] = true;
        dir[objname] = "down";
        startslide(objname);
}

function slideup(objname){
        if(moving[objname])
                return;

        if(document.getElementById(objname).style.display == "none")
                return; // cannot slide up something that is already hidden

        moving[objname] = true;
        dir[objname] = "up";
        startslide(objname);
}

function startslide(objname){
        obj[objname] = document.getElementById(objname);

        endHeight[objname] = parseInt(obj[objname].style.height);
        startTime[objname] = (new Date()).getTime();

        if(dir[objname] == "down"){
                obj[objname].style.height = "1px";
        }

        obj[objname].style.display = "block";

        timerID[objname] = setInterval('slidetick(\'' + objname + '\');',timerlen);
}

function slidetick(objname){
        var elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime[objname];

        if (elapsed > slideAniLen)
                endSlide(objname)
        else {
                var d =Math.round(elapsed / slideAniLen * endHeight[objname]);
                if(dir[objname] == "up")
                        d = endHeight[objname] - d;

                obj[objname].style.height = d + "%";
        }

        return;
}

function endSlide(objname){
        clearInterval(timerID[objname]);

        if(dir[objname] == "up")
                obj[objname].style.display = "none";

        obj[objname].style.height = endHeight[objname] + "%";

        delete(moving[objname]);
        delete(timerID[objname]);
        delete(startTime[objname]);
        delete(endHeight[objname]);
        delete(obj[objname]);
        delete(dir[objname]);

        return;
}

function toggleSlide(objname){
  if(document.getElementById(objname).style.display == "none"){
    // div is hidden, so let's slide down
    slidedown(objname);
  }else{
    // div is not hidden, so slide up
    slideup(objname);
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want the image to be a backround image for the div, or will it be all that is showing?

Comment: Global.... namespace... cluttered.... bleh.

Comment: I made some edits, hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

```
var button = document.getElementById('button_div_id)

function slidedown(objname){
button.style.background = 'image/path.jpg
```

put the same in your slideup, just set the path to the image you want.

or write a function like this...

```
function toggle_visibility() {
     var d = document.getElementById('slidedown');
     var u = document.getElementById('slideup');
     if(d.style.display == 'block') {
        d.style.display = 'none';
        u.style.display = 'block'
     }
     else {
        d.style.display = 'block';
        u.style.display = 'none';
     }
  }
```

and have each image div floated so that when one dissapears, the other will take it's place.  you'll need to have the slideup set to

```
display: none;
```

and slidedown to

```
display: block;
```

and then if you put put the function in the onclick for the tag, it should do what you want it to. 
so...

```
<div id="slideup" onclick="toggle_visibility();">
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Can't get it to work..Here check out this site..picked out a random profile for example..as you can see when you click one of the headers the arrow changes.